# PyQt4 - Using same UI (.ui file) for Windows and Mac

Tags: user-interface, fonts, pyqt, pyqt4, cross-platform

I've developed my GUI application on Mac using PyQt4 Designer. I haven't used any custom font so PyQt4 defaulted to `SF NS Text` (SanFrancisco) and GUI looked similar on every installation as the underlying platform is almost always the same (iMac).

However, I started porting GUI to Windows and out of the box it looks terrible. Font family on Windows is `MS Shell Dlg 2` and font sizes are messed up.

I do not want to use a custom font for my application as the default OS font would give native look and feel. How do I proceed to develop consistent looking UI on both platforms ?

Is it a good idea to maintain different UI files for Mac and Windows ? I'm a little hesitant with this approach as the maintenance is huge with large projects.

Comment: You can set a default font in Designer, select your main window and then choose the font which is available in both platform something like "Georgia" ?

Comment: Is the font explicitly set to SF NS Text in the UI file (is the font family property bold in Qt Designer)? This is _not_ the same as it having a default font of SF NS Text but not being explicitly set to that font. In other words try reverting the font to the default value in Qt Designer then porting it over - it should take on a native font.

Comment: "I do not want to use a custom font for my application as the default OS font would give native look and feel." In that case you have to live with what is there, right?